# Context non equal space after itemize label in RTL document

Tags: lists, context, arabic, right-to-left

Why in this example spaces after `)` of inline itemize environment are not equal, and how to fix this?

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]


\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]


\defineconversion[aralph][أ,ب,ج]

\setupitemgroup[symbol=n,stopper=,right=(]

\starttext

\startitemize[aralph,columns,three][direction=reverse]
\item - 
\item -
\item -
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your items have different widths, but they are occupying a certain width (`width=...`, but no `width=fit`, it seems). You can use `align=left`, and perhaps also set a `distance`, see below. I have also added `\showboxes`, since it helps to see what we get.

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global,method=one]
\setupalign[r2l] 

\setupbodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]


\definefontfamily [myfont][serif][Amiri]   [features=arabic]
\setupbodyfont [myfont]


\defineconversion[aralph][أ,ب,ج]

\setupitemgroup[symbol=n,stopper=,right=(,leftmargin=5mm]

\showboxes

\starttext

\startbuffer
\startitemize[aralph,columns,three][direction=reverse]
\item - 
\item -
\item -
\stopitemize
\stopbuffer

\getbuffer

\setupitemgroup[itemalign=left,distance=1dk]

\getbuffer

\stoptext
```

[image: before and after]